# pyqt5 children access with qml file

Tags: python, qml, pyqt5

I wanted to run qt QSyntaxHighlight example, but building window with QML, not with python code. While I still managed to do so code is awkard and I believe that either my QML or API understanding is wrong.

I created simple QML file with to TextEdits named `main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello")

    TextEdit {
        id: text_view
        objectName: "text_view"
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.8
        color: "black"
        text: qsTr("long class")
        font.pixelSize: 12
        anchors.margins: 5
    }

    TextEdit {
        id: text_input
        anchors.top: text_view.bottom
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height - text_view.height
        color: "#ef1d1d"
        text: qsTr("")
        font.capitalization: Font.MixedCase
        font.pixelSize: 12
    }
}
```

Then added `main.py`:

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QSyntaxHighlighter, QTextDocument
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine, qmlRegisterType


class Highlighter(QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Highlighter, self).__init__(parent)

        keywordFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        keywordFormat.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.darkBlue)
        keywordFormat.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)

        keywordPatterns = ["\\bchar\\b", "\\bclass\\b", "\\bconst\\b",
                "\\bdouble\\b", "\\benum\\b", "\\bexplicit\\b", "\\bfriend\\b",
                "\\binline\\b", "\\bint\\b", "\\blong\\b", "\\bnamespace\\b",
                "\\boperator\\b", "\\bprivate\\b", "\\bprotected\\b",
                "\\bpublic\\b", "\\bshort\\b", "\\bsignals\\b", "\\bsigned\\b",
                "\\bslots\\b", "\\bstatic\\b", "\\bstruct\\b",
                "\\btemplate\\b", "\\btypedef\\b", "\\btypename\\b",
                "\\bunion\\b", "\\bunsigned\\b", "\\bvirtual\\b", "\\bvoid\\b",
                "\\bvolatile\\b"]

        self.highlightingRules = [(QtCore.QRegExp(pattern), keywordFormat)
                for pattern in keywordPatterns]

        classFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        classFormat.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        classFormat.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.darkMagenta)
        self.highlightingRules.append((QtCore.QRegExp("\\bQ[A-Za-z]+\\b"),
                classFormat))

        singleLineCommentFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        singleLineCommentFormat.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.red)
        self.highlightingRules.append((QtCore.QRegExp("//[^\n]*"),
                singleLineCommentFormat))

        self.multiLineCommentFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        self.multiLineCommentFormat.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.red)

        quotationFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        quotationFormat.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.darkGreen)
        self.highlightingRules.append((QtCore.QRegExp("\".*\""), quotationFormat))

        functionFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        functionFormat.setFontItalic(True)
        functionFormat.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.blue)
        self.highlightingRules.append((QtCore.QRegExp("\\b[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?=\\()"), functionFormat))

        self.commentStartExpression = QtCore.QRegExp("/\\*")
        self.commentEndExpression = QtCore.QRegExp("\\*/")

    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        for pattern, format in self.highlightingRules:
            expression = QtCore.QRegExp(pattern)
            index = expression.indexIn(text)
            while index >= 0:
                length = expression.matchedLength()
                self.setFormat(index, length, format)
                index = expression.indexIn(text, index + length)

        self.setCurrentBlockState(0)

        startIndex = 0
        if self.previousBlockState() != 1:
            startIndex = self.commentStartExpression.indexIn(text)

        while startIndex >= 0:
            endIndex = self.commentEndExpression.indexIn(text, startIndex)

            if endIndex == -1:
                self.setCurrentBlockState(1)
                commentLength = len(text) - startIndex
            else:
                commentLength = endIndex - startIndex + self.commentEndExpression.matchedLength()

            self.setFormat(startIndex, commentLength, self.multiLineCommentFormat)
            startIndex = self.commentStartExpression.indexIn(text, startIndex + commentLength)


def print_child(el):
    print(" " * 2 * print_child.max + "type: {}".format(type(el)))
    print(" " * 2 * print_child.max + "name: {}".format(el.objectName()))
    print_child.max += 1
    try:
        for subel in el.children():
            print_child(subel)
    except TypeError:
        pass
    print_child.max -= 1
print_child.max = 0


def child_selector(children, ftype):
    for ch in children:
        if type(ch) is ftype:
            return ch
    return None

if __name__ in "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load("main.qml")
    print_child(engine.rootObjects()[0])
    el = Highlighter(
                child_selector(engine.rootObjects()[0].findChild(QObject, "text_view").children(), QTextDocument)
            )
    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Print child produces this output:

```
type: <class 'PyQt5.QtGui.QWindow'>
name: 
  type: <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QObject'>
  name: 
  type: <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QObject'>
  name: text_view
    type: <class 'PyQt5.QtGui.QTextDocument'>
    name: 
      type: <class 'PyQt5.QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout'>
      name: 
        type: <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QObject'>
        name: 
      type: <class 'PyQt5.QtGui.QTextFrame'>
      name: 
    type: <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QObject'>
    name: 
  type: <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QObject'>
  name: 
    type: <class 'PyQt5.QtGui.QTextDocument'>
    name: 
      type: <class 'PyQt5.QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout'>
      name: 
        type: <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QObject'>
        name: 
      type: <class 'PyQt5.QtGui.QTextFrame'>
      name: 
    type: <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QObject'>
    name:
```

**Questions:**

- I've defined Window with two TextEdits inside, whereas I see that my TextEdits are embedded in additional QObject's ( which is why I had to add `child_selector(...)` and couldn't use findChild output directly ) Why is that and could it be done somehow better?
- Is there some function same as `findChild(...)` but using id not objectName?
- Using findChildren(...) on `engine` without `rootObject()` resulted with `None` I can't get why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**- I've defined Window with two TextEdits inside, whereas I see that my TextEdits are embedded in additional QObject's ( which is why I had to add child_selector(...) and couldn't use findChild output directly ) Why is that and could it be done somehow better**

Yes, you can use findChild, in the following part I show you the solution:

findChild has selectors: the type and the objectName, in the case of textDocument, so as a first test it can be filtered by type, I'll use findChildren since every TextEdit has a textDocument:

```
root = engine.rootObjects()[0]
docs = root.findChildren(QtGui.QTextDocument)
print(docs)
for doc in docs:
    el = Highlighter(doc)
```

**Output:**

```
[<PyQt5.QtGui.QTextDocument object at 0x7f5703eb4af8>, <PyQt5.QtGui.QTextDocument object at 0x7f5703eb4b88>]
```

by applying the filter of the objectname we can filter the textDocument of the first TextEdit:

```
root = engine.rootObjects()[0]
text_view = root.findChild(QtCore.QObject, "text_view")
doc = text_view.findChild(QtGui.QTextDocument)
el = Highlighter(doc)
```

---

**- Is there some function same as findChild(...) but using id not objectName?**

The id only has a meaning in QML so you can not use it from python, also as findChild() and findChildren() only use the objectname and type.

The id is an identifier that depends on the scope, for example:

**MyItem.qml**

```
Item{
    id: root
    // others code
}
```

**main.qml**

```
Window{
    MyItem{
        id: it1
    }
    MyItem{
        id: it2
    }
}
```

As you see, the root id will only identify the Item within MyItem.qml, outside of it it has no meaning, conceptually it is like `this` in c++ or `self` in python, since those properties have a meaning with respect to the scope.

---

**- Using findChildren(...) on engine without rootObject() resulted with None I can't get why?**

QmlEngine is a class that allows to create components, it does not have hierarchical relation, for that reason no element of the tree of hierarchies in QML has like father to the engine, therefore it returns None.

---

I will answer a question made in the comments since the answer deserves it.

*QTextDocument inherits from QObject so it has objectName, so as QTextDocument is a property of TextEdit can it objectName be set in QML somehow?*

Unfortunately it is not possible to place an objectName in QML to the QTextDocument since in QML the QTextDocument is not accessible. If we review the docs:

[textDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#textDocument-prop) is a property of [TextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html) that is a [QQuickTextDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquicktextdocument.html), and that [QQuickTextDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquicktextdocument.html) has a method call [textDocument()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquicktextdocument.html#textDocument) that just returns a [QTextDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html) but that method is not a `Q_INVOKABLE` nor a `SLOT`.

Something closer to what you want is to set an objectName to the [textDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#textDocument-prop) and then get the [QTextDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html) with the [textDocument()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquicktextdocument.html#textDocument) method (maybe it will be confusing since the names are similar), to set the objectName we will use the Component.OnCompleted signal:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello")

    TextEdit {
        id: text_view
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.8
        color: "black"
        text: qsTr("long class")
        font.pixelSize: 12
        anchors.margins: 5
        Component.onCompleted: text_view.textDocument.objectName = "textDocument1"
    }

    TextEdit {
        id: text_input
        anchors.top: text_view.bottom
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height - text_view.height
        color: "#ef1d1d"
        text: qsTr("")
        font.capitalization: Font.MixedCase
        font.pixelSize: 12
        Component.onCompleted: text_input.textDocument.objectName = "textDocument2"
    }
}
```

***.py**

```
# ...

if __name__ in "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load("main.qml")
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    root = engine.rootObjects()[0]

    q_text_document1 = root.findChild(QtQuick.QQuickTextDocument, "textDocument1")
    h1 = Highlighter(q_text_document1.textDocument())

    q_text_document2 = root.findChild(QtQuick.QQuickTextDocument, "textDocument2")
    h2 = Highlighter(q_text_document2.textDocument())

    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Although I personally prefer not to expose the elements created in QML to python/C++ through the objectName since QML handles its life cycle and not python/C++. In this case I prefer to export the class as a new Item, and create a slot to pass the property of the `QQuickTextDocument`:

**main.py**

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQml, QtQuick

class Highlighter(QtGui.QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Highlighter, self).__init__(parent)

        keywordFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        keywordFormat.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.darkBlue)
        keywordFormat.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)

        keywordPatterns = ["\\bchar\\b", "\\bclass\\b", "\\bconst\\b",
                "\\bdouble\\b", "\\benum\\b", "\\bexplicit\\b", "\\bfriend\\b",
                "\\binline\\b", "\\bint\\b", "\\blong\\b", "\\bnamespace\\b",
                "\\boperator\\b", "\\bprivate\\b", "\\bprotected\\b",
                "\\bpublic\\b", "\\bshort\\b", "\\bsignals\\b", "\\bsigned\\b",
                "\\bslots\\b", "\\bstatic\\b", "\\bstruct\\b",
                "\\btemplate\\b", "\\btypedef\\b", "\\btypename\\b",
                "\\bunion\\b", "\\bunsigned\\b", "\\bvirtual\\b", "\\bvoid\\b",
                "\\bvolatile\\b"]

        self.highlightingRules = [(QtCore.QRegExp(pattern), keywordFormat)
                for pattern in keywordPatterns]

        classFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        classFormat.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        classFormat.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.darkMagenta)
        self.highlightingRules.append((QtCore.QRegExp("\\bQ[A-Za-z]+\\b"),
                classFormat))

        singleLineCommentFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        singleLineCommentFormat.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.red)
        self.highlightingRules.append((QtCore.QRegExp("//[^\n]*"),
                singleLineCommentFormat))

        self.multiLineCommentFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        self.multiLineCommentFormat.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.red)

        quotationFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        quotationFormat.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.darkGreen)
        self.highlightingRules.append((QtCore.QRegExp("\".*\""), quotationFormat))

        functionFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        functionFormat.setFontItalic(True)
        functionFormat.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.blue)
        self.highlightingRules.append((QtCore.QRegExp("\\b[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?=\\()"), functionFormat))

        self.commentStartExpression = QtCore.QRegExp("/\\*")
        self.commentEndExpression = QtCore.QRegExp("\\*/")

    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        for pattern, format in self.highlightingRules:
            expression = QtCore.QRegExp(pattern)
            index = expression.indexIn(text)
            while index >= 0:
                length = expression.matchedLength()
                self.setFormat(index, length, format)
                index = expression.indexIn(text, index + length)

        self.setCurrentBlockState(0)

        startIndex = 0
        if self.previousBlockState() != 1:
            startIndex = self.commentStartExpression.indexIn(text)

        while startIndex >= 0:
            endIndex = self.commentEndExpression.indexIn(text, startIndex)

            if endIndex == -1:
                self.setCurrentBlockState(1)
                commentLength = len(text) - startIndex
            else:
                commentLength = endIndex - startIndex + self.commentEndExpression.matchedLength()

            self.setFormat(startIndex, commentLength, self.multiLineCommentFormat)
            startIndex = self.commentStartExpression.indexIn(text, startIndex + commentLength)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtQuick.QQuickTextDocument)
    def setQQuickTextDocument(self, q):
        if isinstance(q, QtQuick.QQuickTextDocument):
            self.setDocument(q.textDocument())


if __name__ in "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    QtQml.qmlRegisterType(Highlighter, "Foo", 1, 0, "Highlighter")
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load("main.qml")
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    root = engine.rootObjects()[0]
    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import Foo 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello")

    TextEdit {
        id: text_view
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.8
        color: "black"
        text: qsTr("long class")
        font.pixelSize: 12
        anchors.margins: 5
    }

    Highlighter{
        id: h1
        Component.onCompleted: h1.setQQuickTextDocument(text_view.textDocument)
    }

    TextEdit {
        id: text_input
        anchors.top: text_view.bottom
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height - text_view.height
        color: "#ef1d1d"
        text: qsTr("")
        font.capitalization: Font.MixedCase
        font.pixelSize: 12
    }

    Highlighter{
        id: h2
        Component.onCompleted: h2.setQQuickTextDocument(text_input.textDocument)
    }

}
```

With this last method the life cycle of the objects is handled by QML, with the initial methods QML could eliminate some item and python/C++ would not know it since nobody notifies it.

Comment: 1: I actually use findChild the very way shown, so there isn't any better/cleaner way to select QTextDocument by objectName? I Thought that TextEdit is being one to one translated to QTextDocument, but as I see it's QObject with QTextDocument inside? To be more exact I wanted to have one call of findChild to get QTextDocument by objectName.

2:I don't get why ID don't have meaning outside QML :) 
3:As for QmlEngine - so why does it have findChildren(...) available? For what purpose? It might not have hierarchical relation, jet as it can give rootObjects() it kind of starts the tree.

Comment: I've asked this question to get as clear view as possible, to get a good understanding of 'why' looking for some more info I could find in docs. A bit deeper explanations would be much appreciated.

Comment: @pholat 1. QTextDocument does not have an objectName so you can not access it directly, you have to access it through TextEdit. 2. ID only has meaning for QML, it is made by design since in declarative languages it is customary to identify each element by the id. 3. QmlEngine is a QObject so it will have the method findChildren since QmlEngine can have children, but when a window is built it has a root element and the items that are inside that window are children of that root.

Comment: @pholat Do you have any other questions?

Comment: @pholat In conclusion: 1. The QTextDocument can not be accessed because it does not have an objectName. 2. ID by design has a meaning only in QML. 3.Every QObject can have children, so QmlEngine can have children but that does not mean that the goal of findchildren is to obtain items, the goal is simply to obtain the children, and that feature is used to obtain the items.

Comment: thanks. 1: QTextDocument inherits from QObject so it has objectName, so as QTextDocument is a property of TextEdit can it objectName be set in QML somehow? 2: I get that it was designed that way, but I don't get why, there had to be some reason for that?

Comment: @pholat 1. I am working on implementing what you signal. 2. the id only has meaning within the scope, for example if I create a component the root can have an id, and when the instance could have another id, for example: MyItem.qml `Item{id: root}` and in main.qml : `Window {MyItem {id: item1} MyItem {id: item2}}`, so the id is not a unique property, it depends on the scope, so it is not accessible from the outside and as you can see in QML is limited.

Comment: @pholat  I already added more information in my answer, if you have any doubt about it tell me, on the other hand if my answer helps you do not forget to mark my answer as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour], that is the best way to thank